# Transferring membershiops, or an alternative approach to on behalf of memberships

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

We have a membership type for individuals, but it may be that their employer is paying for their membership, so we added the "on behalf of" option to enable individuals to add their employer's details. This works fine, but the membership gets added to the organisation rather than the individuals. Is there a way to override this somehow to the employer is still added but the membership remains with the individual registering? Or is there an easy way the site admins can transfer memberships between the employer and the individual?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: you are right that the 'on behalf of' is geared to individuals paying on behalf of an organisation - not the other way round. In a way, this has similarities to the concept of a gift membership, ie Contact A pays for it but Contact B gets it - but quickly skimming extensions am not sure there is something there for you. if you were Drupal i would test a webform solution